# Using Yahoo! database without quantmod functions

Tags: r, loops, yahoo-finance

The problem I am trying to solve is looping a string through R with Yahoo! finance api. This would make a bunch of data frame files, but if I could convert it into `xts`, that would be awesome. However, the `xts` part is not as important.

```
library(quantmod)
DB <- quantmod:::DDB_Yahoo()       
for (i in length(DB$db)){
  symbols <- DB$db[i] #symbols are c('AAIT', 'AAL', 'AAME', ...   #Thousands Essentially 
URL <- "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=symbols"
dat[i] <- read.csv(URL[i])
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I know that we can't have symbols in ("") quotations, but it is for logical purposes.

p.s. For this instance, I am not using `quantmod` functions on purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x<-c('AAIT', 'AAL', 'AAME')
kk<-lapply(x,function(i) download.file(paste0("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=",i),paste0(i,".csv")))
```

if you want to directly read the file:

```
jj<- lapply(x,function(i) read.csv(paste0("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=",i)))
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do I apply it to `library(quantmod)
DB <- quantmod:::DDB_Yahoo()
Stocks <- as.matrix(DB$db)
yahoodatabase <- function(){}
for (i in length(DB$db)){
  symbols <- DB$db[i]
  return(symbols)}
URL <- lapply(x,function(i) read.csv(paste0("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=",i)))
dat[i] <- read.csv(URL[i])
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
}`

Comment: My bad: This is better, but I get an error `for (i in length(DB$db)){
symbols <- DB$db[i]
URL <- lapply(symbols,function(i) read.csv(paste0("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=",i)))
dat[i] <- read.csv(URL[i])
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
}
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection`

Comment: Why are you reading the file twice? You also don't need for loop when you already have lapply.

Comment: You just need to replace x with DB . Also, if this works, please mark the answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Totally sick man. Sweet!!! `symbols <- DB$db
kk<-lapply(symbols,function(i) download.file(paste0("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=",i),paste0(i,".csv")))'

Comment: I was going to, I know :D